# list selected items in shapeEditor

Tags: maya, mel

How do I list the currently selected items in the {blend}shape editor ? I have tried using the [blendShapePanel](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/blendShapePanel.html), [blendShapeEditor](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/blendShapeEditor.html) and [shapeEditor](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/blendShapeEditor.html) querying the following strings (panels, editors, or windows):

- `blendShapeEditorTreeViewSelection`
- `shapePanel1`
- `shapePanel1Window`

but in vain.

*Note: I have obtained the above names using the [lsUI](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/lsUI.html) command*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MEL proc `getShapeEditorTreeviewSelection`. To get the currently selected blend shapes:

```
getShapeEditorTreeviewSelection(1);
// Result: blendShape1 //
```

Then to get the currently selected targets:

```
getShapeEditorTreeviewSelection(4);
// Result: blendShape1.0 blendShape1.1 //
```

This gives you back the blend shape and the index of each selected target. To convert the index, we can do:

```
string $selectedTargetL[] = getShapeEditorTreeviewSelection(4);
string $convertedTargetL[] = {};
for($target in $selectedTargetL)
{
    string $subStrings[] = stringToStringArray($target, ".");
    $convertedTargetL[size($convertedTargetL)] = eval("aliasAttr -q " + $subStrings[0] + ".w[" + $subStrings[1] + "]");
}
print $convertedTargetL;
pSphere1
pSphere4
```

And that will get you everything that was selected. If you need more information about the command, Autodesk has a lot of documentation for that proc in the file listed with the MEL `whatIs getShapeEditorTreeviewSelection`. I'm not sure I can post it here though.

I found that command by making blend shapes with the Shape Editor and searching `<maya install directory>/scripts` for the procs echoed in the Script Editor, then searching through similar commands.

Hope this helps!